# Handle empty JSON values in Java

Tags: java, json

I can't seem to work out how to deal with a null value in a JSON string,

```
[,63,11303571428571429]
```

Any attempt to test `data.toArray()[0].toString() == null` just causes a NullPointerException.

Any clue how to handle this and return a null?

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: Also, how are you going to call `toString` on a `null` reference? Just `data.toArray()[0] == null`.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't really help. It's what gets returned from the service I'm using and can be processed by the deserializer.

Comment: Find a better deserializer and use a better service.

Comment: @user5839 the problem is the first comma. If that's a recurrent error and you can't modify the server, I'd say just erase it somehow, like with `"[" + dataString.substring(2)`. Superquirky, but it works.

Comment: It's Google Analytics data, it's the only service I've got! Your first useful comment seems to be the right answer,  Sotirios Delimanolis add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

data.toArray()[0] == null